# Best practice to access outer class variable in static nested class anonymous method Java

Tags: java, oop, memory-management, memory-leaks

In my android based application I am having an anonymous function i.e. an `onClick Listener` inside my static `InnerClass` which access a view from the `OuterClass`.. the issue is as i try to access the particular view from desired location it states that the non static member cannot be accessed from the a static perspective... As I make the view from OuterClass static it works but is it a good practice? doesn't it lead to any sort of memory leak? What can be done in that case?

```
public class OuterClass extends CustomAppCompatActiivity {
static EditText city_et;
 public static class InnerClass extends DialogFragment {
 @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        //the view to access
                        city_et.setText("");

                    }
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

 }


}
```

Comment: Which is it? Static nested class, or inner class. It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: edited the answer

Comment: So what you have now is a class named `InnerClass` which isn't an inner class. Please clarify further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static nested class `InnerClass` cannot access members of the enclosing instance, because an instance of `InnerClass` may not be owned by `OuterClass`. Imagine this:

```
public class Outer {
    public String out = "out";

    public static class StaticInner {
        public void printEnclosing() {
            System.out.println(Outer.this.out); // Let's say this compiles
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticInner si = new StaticInner();
        si.printEnclosing();
    }
}
```

Note that an instance of `Outer` was never ever made. Then how is it possible to print the value of `out`?

What you need is inner class. Inner class cannot be instantiated by anyone other than the enclosing class, or its subclasses. This ensure that the only time you can instantiate the inner class is when there is already an instance of the outer class.

```
public class Outer {
    public String out = "out";
    public Inner inner = new Inner();

    public class Inner {   
        public void printEnclosing() {
            System.out.println(Outer.this.out); // "out" can be safely referenced
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inner inner = new Inner(); // Compile-time error

        Outer out = new Outer();
        out.inner.printEnclosing(); // This works, because you are calling method of the Inner class instance owned by Outer class.
    }
}
```

Therefore, this is what your code should look like:

```
public class OuterClass extends CustomAppCompatActiivity {
    private EditText city_et;
    private final InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();
    public class InnerClass extends DialogFragment {
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //the view to access
                    city_et.setText("");

                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public InnerClass getInnerClass() {
        return inner;
    }
}
```

#### Update

For your concern on memory leak, I think the question is: What are the roles of `InnerClass` and `OuterClass`. Everytime you can create an `InnerClass` instance (or a collection of `InnerClass` instances) is when you have a new `OuterClass`. `InnerClass` needs the reference of `OuterClass` in order to call `setText()`.

Therefore the contract here is: `InnerClass` can't exist without `OuterClass`, and an `InnerClass` always have an `InnerClass`. `InnerClass` will be garbage collected together with `OuterClass`.

If the relationship between `InnerClass` and `OuterClass` is that `InnerClass` can function without `OuterClass`, and all you need is the `EditText city_et` reference, then you should pass that reference in. Since `InnerClass` is independent from `OuterClass` now, you can use static nested class, or simply move it to another separate class.

```
public class OuterClass extends CustomAppCompatActiivity {
    private EditText city_et;

    public static class InnerClass extends DialogFragment {
        private EditText city_et;

        public InnerClass(EditText city_et) { // Pass a reference in
            this.city_et = city_et;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            okBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //the view to access
                    city_et.setText("");

                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This way, an `OuterClass` instance can be garbage collected whenever it is qualified to do so, independent of `InnerClass`. The only reference that cannot be garbage collected is that `EditText` instance.

#### Update 2

EJP pointed out that "Inner class cannot be instantiated by anyone other than the enclosing class, or its subclasses" is wrong, and after checking out, he's right. On top of that, the term "inner class" is the official term for "non-static nested class."

However, you should still use a static nested class or a separate class if you think that the `DialogFragment` subclass could live longer than the enclosing class.

Comment: Non static inner classes do hold a reference to their parent classes. The problem with making a inner class non-static is that you always hold a reference to the OuterClass. making it leakable?

Comment: great that was what i was concerned about thanks for your effort

Comment: 'Inner class cannot be instantiated by anyone other than the enclosing class, or its subclasses' is false.

Comment: @mrdebug 'Non-static inner class' is a tautology, and 'making a[n] inner class non-static' is ditto.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer without knowing the full context. Most probably `EditText city_et` is not *static* and is made only to compile the code. (Does all instances of `OuterClass` have the same `city_et` - I don't thinks so).

You can pass the `city_et` as a parameter to the `RecyclerDialogFragment` constructor and store it as an instance variable so that you have a static nested class and not an inner class.

Comment: yes its made static as it wasn't accessible inside the nested class due to its static nature